# How to do a regression of a log-return on date

Tags: r, lm, quantmod

I am a total R newbie
So pardon me for this silly question
I want to do a regression of the stock log return on time
But I don't know how to extract the date as the X variable

[Here is the R data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYy6u.png)

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMZN",src='yahoo',from="2010-01-01", to="2018-01-01")
Returns=dailyReturn(AMZN,subset=NULL,type='log',leading=TRUE)
lm(Returns,?????)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is ``arima``?

Comment: Thanks for answering. No, just a simple regression against time

Comment: ``arima`` is Time Series Regression. What you have is a time series, you can use ``arima`` in R to perform regression (x would be the time variable)

Comment: I know, but how to do it in the simple linear regression ?
The professor explicitly stated "Perform a simple linear regression of the log-return on time. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Returns` will be an xts object, so you need to use the `index()` function.

```r
model <- lm(Returns$daily.returns ~ index(Returns))
```

Regardless of the model you end up building, `index(Returns)` will get you the vector of dates.